# Cakephp relations not working

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am using relations in cakephp models to retrieve the data, Here i want to retrieve the Posts and their comments, also it should return the userdetails for posts as well as comments, here while selecting data i am getting the user details for only the posts not for comments, i need the user data for comments also.

How can i get the userdetails of comments ?

Here is my find:

```
$post = $this->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>'1')));
```

Following are the models:

Post.php

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Post';
var $useTable = 'posts';
var $primaryKey = 'id';

var $hasMany = array(

    'Comment' => array(
    'className' => 'Comment','limit' => 4,
            'order' => 'created ASC'));

var $belongsTo = array(
    'User'=> array ('className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id')
);
}
?>
```

Comment.php

```
 <?php
 class Comment extends AppModel {

 var $name = 'Comment';
 var $useTable = 'comments';
 var $primaryKey = 'id';

 var $belongsTo = array(
    'Post'=> array ('className' => 'Post',
    'foreignKey' => 'post_id','counterCache' => true ),

    'User'=> array ('className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id')
);
 }
 ?>
```

User.php

```
 <?php
 class User extends AppModel {

 var $name = 'User';
 var $useTable = 'users';
 var $primaryKey = 'id';

 var $hasMany = array(
   'Comment' => array('className' => 'Comment',
   'Post' => array('className' => 'Post')));
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the recursive property in the find method:

The recursive property defines how deep CakePHP should go to fetch associated model data via find(), and read() methods.

Imagine your application features Groups which belong to a domain and have many Users which in turn have many Articles. You can set $recursive to different values based on the amount of data you want back from a $this->Group->find() call:

-1 CakePHP fetches Group data only, no joins.

0 CakePHP fetches Group data and its domain.

1 CakePHP fetches a Group, its domain and its associaed Users

2 CakePHP fetches a Group, its domain, its associated Users, and the Users’ associated Articles

Your query would become:

$post = $this->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>'1'), 'recursive' => x));

where x is the the depth level of the associations